# How do I attach data file?

Tags: support

I want to post a question on how to open a certain data file in Mathematica. How do I attach the file to my post?

Comment: What's the file type?

Comment: it is an image of .tiff type

Comment: You might want to look at any number of image hosts that can host *.tiff files; hopefully your file isn't too large.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2005/21532)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your image is smaller than 2 MiB you can just attach it directly. 
(By pressing Ctrl+G or clicking the insert image icon)

[image: Image icon]

If not, you can try any of the multitude of image hosting platforms (such as https://postimage.org/) and post a link.

The problem is how reliable these are. So to be on the safe side, it s advisable to include a smaller image in the post.

[Figshare](https://figshare.com/) is also an interesting option, although only meant for scientific results.

Comment: how do I include the image in the post?

Comment: @Luigi You can click on the image icon or press Ctrl+G